# Laravel 10 error message: Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager

Tags: laravel, authentication, crud, middleware, laravel-10

I have the following issues on Laravel and testing a login:

> Undefined property:
> Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::${"id":1,"name":"Clark
> Kent","email":"clark.kent@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2023-05-17T23:13:35.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-05-17T23:13:35.000000Z"}

when i supposed to be on home page after login

code look like that in HTTP MIDDLEWARE RedirectIfAuthenticated

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, go 1 step back. You're on a forn and you're posting to a route, *show that route*, then you get redirected (?), *show the route group, middleware, everything*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.